# How to check if point is placed inside contour?

Tags: python, opencv, contour, opencv3.0

I have drawn a contour around extreme points. Inside polygon figure I have others points.
How to check if they are inside contour?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `cv2.pointPolygonTest()` function available in OpenCV.

For example:

`dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,(50,50),True)`

In this example we are checking whether the coordinate `(50, 50)` is present withing the contour `cnt`

1. `dist` returns one of the following three:

   - **Positive** value if the point is **inside** the contour
   - **Negative** value if the point is **outside** the contour
   - **Zero** if the point is **on** the contour
2. Within the function `cv2.pointPolygonTest()` the third parameter decides whether you want one of the following two :

   - If it is **True**, `dist` returns either the positive or negative distance of the point, if it is either inside or outside the contour respectively.
   - On the other hand, if it is set to **False**, it returns +1, -1 or 0 depending on the point lying inside, outside or on the contour respectively

See [THE DOCS](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html) for more details

### **Illustration:**

I added an example to show how it works. I considered the following image for which a contour was obtained:

[image]

I assumed the following points to be used as illustration:

`(50, 70), (170, 152), (152, 48)`

[image]

```
dist1 = cv2.pointPolygonTest(contours[0], (50, 70), True) #green 
dist2 = cv2.pointPolygonTest(contours[0], (170, 152), True) #blue
dist3 = cv2.pointPolygonTest(contours[0], (152, 48), True) #red

print('dist1 : ', dist1)
print('dist2 : ', dist2)
print('dist3 : ', dist3)
```

**Output:**

```
('dist1 : ', -45.17742799230607)
('dist2 : ', 49.9799959983992)
('dist3 : ', -0.0)
```

Comment: Can I use this function to chek if point inside polygon?

Comment: Yes. The polygon you are using must be passed as a contour

Comment: Okay I draw polygon as: `pts = np.array(b, np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
cv2.polylines(image,[pts],True,(0,255,0))`

Comment: What I must to pass for `cv2.pointPolygonTest`?  `pts`?

Comment: Yes. Pass in one point at a time. If you have a bunch of points to test, pass them one after the other in a `list`.

Comment: Thx. I created a tetragon and have checked the position of the point inside them: L_DANGEROUS_ZONE = [ [57,356], [357,343], [828,847], [319,1069] ]
    ctr_dng = np.array(L_DANGEROUS_ZONE).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32) dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(ctr_dng,(center_x, center_y), True)
        if dist >= 0:
            k_dng += 1

Comment: Strangely, this function requires that the contour be of `np.dtype=int`.